# How to get the id of the element that is clicked on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, user-interface

I have this situation. I have a JavaScript function that does some work on document click:

```
$(document).click(function () {
//---Some work is done---
});
```

But I also want to check which document element is clicked? So, how can I get the clicked element id anywhere in the whole document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element from which the event was originated can be referred using the event's target property

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    var id = e.target.id
});
```

Note: this will work only if all elements in your page has an `id` attribute.

Another approach could be to find the closest element with has an id like

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).closest('[id]').attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
//---Some work is done---
 var id = e.target.id;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F39Gs/)